# Sending an Email via node -red

Tags: node-red

I'm trying to send an Email via node-red. For that I've created a gmail account and setup the POP and IMAP activ! 
After that I've  made the following flow:
[image]

the receiving node has the following proprieties : 
[image]

after deploying the flow I get the following error :

```
Error: Invalid login: 534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbvv534-5.7.14 -rKtG5Is_XTSKJwG-_w0KiX10YiqY5HHJZI2Otb1tfXteDxZCdPF1g_pvBv2A0fAG0SiFB534-5.7.14 
    C5suewv6vlY84IYL4IoWhwRIOYlIkX--dsk5IxFMicNHF9Vqhr9zlLez3rhrQpH2O3NMwO534-
5.7.14 6J8D5EEgncdWLsBKkSTy2dQdSOgawCPL_0YEEkmD11eU-ljlToU55Bs-JQYvP7NCVdvvD9534-
5.7.14 GCvhZrfwFLlHBCIpJXkceDZXZOP4tsZTclozixU0_6vAlDKQ8d-xFgtwHbY5OwWob2134r534-5.7.14 T28dhvV7WeXR5pCsSOunnV0eZs21OL0Y3QiY-AkU6lM2CVqHZp-GAKoG9v7WEsRbpQsCvA534-5.7.14 sTipJYcUUOyYu-sNPn3PgmS1LrhI24Ie2LLImKespg3g5EqR5BqoZ52mlz3Q45sCDcn-HC534-5.7.14 Xbm5LKr70K51JYsYfDm4uodPuTLYppSsDO_6RmnsegWLBBvUdbwsIRIqNPkAbc5Tx3fmJE534-5.7.14 o61vw> Please log in via your web browser and then try again.534-5.7.14  Learn more at534 5.7.14  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 ay16-v6sm476249ejb.20 - gsmtp
```

the password is correct so I don't what I'm missing here?

Does anybody has an idea how may I solve this !

Comment: Have you followed the link in the error message? https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the error is generated because gmail is blocking Apps from using the account, even after POP3/ IMAP free! One needs to  generate an App password, and use this as Email Password in the node!

Answer (score 1):

The error message contains a link to help message which explains the possible problems: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754

> **I can't sign in to my email client**
>
> If you can't sign in to your email
>   client, you might see one of these errors:
>
> - "Username and password not accepted"
> - "Invalid credentials"
> - You're asked to enter your username and password over and over
>
> **Step 1: Check your password**
>
> If you have these problems or can’t sign in, first check
>   to make sure you’re using the right password.
>
> **Step 2: Try these troubleshooting steps**
>
> - Update your email client to the latest version.
> - Use an App Password: If you use 2-Step
>     Verification, try signing in with an App Password.
> - Allow less secure
>     apps: If you don't use 2-Step Verification, you might need to allow
>     less secure apps to access your account.
> - If you recently changed your
>     Gmail password, you might need to re-enter your Gmail account
>     information or completely repeat your Gmail account setup on your
>     other email client.
> - If the tips above didn't help, visit
>     https://www.google.com/accounts/DisplayUnlockCaptcha and follow the
>     steps on the page.
> - The email client's sign-in method might be
>     insecure. Try signing in directly on the Gmail app.
> - Make sure your
>     mail app isn't set to check for new email too frequently. If your mail
>     app checks for new messages more than once every 10 minutes, the app’s
>     access to your account could be blocked.

In this case the problem is most likely that you will need to follow the link to allow less secure apps to sign into your account (https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255) or create a App Password